# I'm not able to edit link using experience manager

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

I'm not able to edit `${item.link}` which creates anchor tag in the browser output using Experience Manager (xpm). Rest text or label is editable using xpm.

1. I have integrated my UI design in views (jsp files) like `FooterLinks.jsp`, `HeaderLinks.jsp` etc.
2. I'm testing my pages from localhost development environment.
3. As we know xpm (Experience manager) is used for inline editing for text, image, links on web page.
4. In my case all text are inline editable but not links editable though it shows green border around links.

Hope these steps will help you to understand my question.

Comment: Please help yourself by expanding on the details on your question. What exact steps are you following, what behavior are you seeing and what behavior are you expecting. At the moment, all we know is that _something_ isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange, Chandrakant. Bart Koopman and Jonathan Williams describe [ways to handle links within Experience Manager in this question](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/10807/46).

Comment: I've tried to edit your question to let it make more sense, but there still are a lot of questions I have before I can give you a solid answer. Can you EDIT your question and add some relevant information in there like: what Templating model are you using (are you publishing JSPs or are you using something like DD4T perhaps), what is the generated HTML of the page (the bit where the editable link should be) looking like etc.?

Answer (score 2):

What I understood from your question is that you want to edit your link from XPM.

Yes, you can edit both text and URL of the link. For text you need to do code similarly what you are doing for other text of the site and for link url you can put your link field as metadata field and while doing editing from XPM you can easily do editing by seleting the metadata properties for Component presentation.

Thanks
Nash